# How do you deny a user access to a certain collection in mongo?

Tags: security, database, mongodb

I have several collections that I would not like certain users to see. How would I go about "hiding" them or blocking a user from viewing?

Answer (score 1):

This directly depends on the security model you are currently using.

Check the online documentation regarding [access control](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/access-control/). Specifically, [user privileges](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/)